# Stored procedure for inserting data from one table to another in different database

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have  pair of tables in the format MASTER TABLE and SECONDARY TABLE both in different databases. I have a dblink which connects these databases. secondary table is an empty table and both tables have same structure. Now i would like to insert all the datas of master table in one db to secondary table in another db using stored procedures. I couldnt find any posts regarding transfer of datas using different db. I am new to PL/SQL. Could somebody help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a query like below:

```
INSERT INTO database1.dbo.mastertable(col1,col2,....)
  SELECT col1, col2,...... FROM database2.dbo.secondarytable;
```

Comment: query between the begin and end statement of stored procedures ryt?

Comment: Yes, use this query inside your SP.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a stored proc. You can call  the secondary database by name via the DB Link.

```
create or replace procedure proc_name as
begin
  insert into secondary_table@remotedb select * from primary_table;
  commit;
end;
```

The @remotedb refers to the DB link you've created to allow access to the remote database.

Edited to add PL/SQL proc

Comment: need a stored procedure since i need to do this on a timely scheduled manner.

Comment: Added a stored proc wrapper for calling via a job